# pygame scrolling dialogue text

Tags: python, pygame

I would create a sort of "scrolling dialogue" like in the old point and click.
I'll try to explain better:

I have the following text: "Hello World".
I would print in the screen letter by letter: "H" (1 sec after) "e" (1 sec after) "l" etc etc..

i tried to do in this way:

```
font = pygame.font.Font("orangekid.ttf", 25)
text = font.render("A long time ago", True, (0, 128, 0))


        pygame.display.update()
        for i in range(len("A long time ago")):
            display_game.fill(BLACK)
            display_game.blit(text[i],(400+i, 300))

            clock.tick(60)
```

but it gives me an error about the text[i].

How can i solve the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here, you render the entire text to a `Surface`:

```py
text = font.render("A long time ago", True, (0, 128, 0))
```

Here, you iterate over a string:

```py
for i in range(len("A long time ago")):
    display_game.fill(BLACK)
    display_game.blit(text[i],(400+i, 300))
```

`text` is a Surface, not a string anymore, so you can't index it like a string and hope to get a part of the text. The `Surface` named `text` does not know if it contains text or not.

Also, you have to use some kind of timer to change the text every second.

Here's a simple example of how you could do what you want:

```py
import pygame
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

font = pygame.font.Font(None, 25)

# raise the USEREVENT every 1000ms
pygame.time.set_timer(pygame.USEREVENT, 200)

# generate a generator that scrolls through the letters
# given a string foo, it will return
# f
# fo
# foo
def text_generator(text):
    tmp = ''
    for letter in text:
        tmp += letter
        # don't pause for spaces
        if letter != ' ':
            yield tmp

# a simple class that uses the generator
# and can tell if it is done
class DynamicText(object):
    def __init__(self, font, text, pos, autoreset=False):
        self.done = False
        self.font = font
        self.text = text
        self._gen = text_generator(self.text)
        self.pos = pos
        self.autoreset = autoreset
        self.update()
    
    def reset(self):
        self._gen = text_generator(self.text)
        self.done = False
        self.update()
        
    def update(self):
        if not self.done:
            try: self.rendered = self.font.render(next(self._gen), True, (0, 128, 0))
            except StopIteration: 
                self.done = True
                if self.autoreset: self.reset()

    def draw(self, screen):
        screen.blit(self.rendered, self.pos)
            
message = DynamicText(font, "A long time ago...", (200, 200), autoreset=True)
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: break
        if event.type == pygame.USEREVENT: message.update()
    else:
        screen.fill(pygame.color.Color('black'))
        message.draw(screen)
        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(60)
        continue
    break
pygame.quit()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the example you gave, 'text' is a surface (font.render renders a surface based on the string you give it). What you want to do is iterate over a string, and then render it to a surface.

Another thing I would change is the "(400+i, 300)", because letters are more than one pixel in width, so moving the coordinates by only one pixel would have them overlap. I would suggest using the font.size function to determine the new coordinates.

Example:

```
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 48)
string = "A long time ago"
windowSurface.fill(BLACK)
for i in range(len(string)):
    text = font.render(string[i], True, (0, 128, 0))
    windowSurface.blit(text,(400 + (font.size(string[:i])[0]), 300))
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(2)
```