# Why is my text being duplicated instead of wrapped in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame, word-wrap

I'm writing a basic text-based game with pygame (I'm not too experienced and this is my first question), and I took word-wrapping and animating the letters in a sequence from the two pages in the class docstring and sort of combined them. Right now, the text animates, but if there's a word that should start a new line it doesn't wrap and behaves as it does in the second attachment (duplicates on new line). Wasn't sure what to search online for this. Python 3.8.5; pygame 2.1.2.

```py
class DynamicText:
    """
    Displays and word-wraps text.
    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42014195/rendering-text-with-multiple-lines-in-pygame
    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31381169/pygame-scrolling-dialogue-text
    """
    def __init__(self, text, pos, font, color=WHITE, autoreset=False):
        self.done = False
        self.font = font
        self.text = text
        self._gen = self.text_generator(self.text)
        self.pos = pos
        self.color= color
        self.autoreset = autoreset
        self.update()
    
    def reset(self):
        self._gen = self.text_generator(self.text)
        self.done = False
        self.update()
        
    def update(self):
        if not self.done:
            try: self.word_wrap()
            except StopIteration: 
                self.done = True
                if self.autoreset: self.reset()
    
    def word_wrap(self):
        words = [word.split(' ') for word in self.text.splitlines()]  # 2D array where each row is a list of words.
        space = self.font.size(' ')[0]  # The width of a space.
        max_width, max_height = textsurface.get_size()
        x, y = self.pos
        for line in words: #This is what actually renders the text!
            word_surface = self.rendered = self.font.render((next(self._gen)), True, self.color) 
            word_width, word_height = word_surface.get_size()
            if x + word_width >= max_width:
                x = self.pos[0]  # Reset the x.
                y += word_height  # Start on new row.
            textsurface.blit(word_surface, (x, y))
            x += word_width + space
        x = self.pos[0]  # Reset the x.
        y += word_height  # Start on new row.
    
    def text_generator(self,text):
            tmp = ""
            for letter in text:
                tmp += letter
                # don't pause for spaces
                if letter != " ":
                    yield tmp
```

```py
if __name__=='__main__':
    running=True
    ds=DoStuff() #makes screen, textbox, image rect
    msg=DynamicText("Hey, does rendering this work? What about actual multiline text?", (10,10), textdata, WHITE)
    while running:
        screen.blit(textsurface,(20,10))
        screen.blit(imgsurface,(650,10))
        clock.tick(60)
        pg.display.update()
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type==QUIT:
                running=False
            if event.type==pg.USEREVENT:
                msg.update()
    pg.quit()
    sys.exit()
```

What it does with one line (correct)

[image: What it does with one line (correct)]

What it does with text that's supposed to be wrapped (incorrect)

[image: What it does with text that's supposed to be wrapped (incorrect)]

Answer (score 0):

you should add the line division from [the first question linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42014195/rendering-text-with-multiple-lines-in-pygame) in this question. As well as you can use something like this:

```
body = ['Be careful with your inputs, game does not have good error handling!',
                'To choose who begins the game input "a" for computer or "b" for yourself',
                'Press enter to play']
        label = []
        for line in range(len(body)):
            label.append(word_font.render(body[line], True, yellow)) #creates text lable

        for line in range(len(label)):
            disp.blit(label[line], [display_w / 5, 150 + 25 * line]) #positions the text
```

Comment: What do you mean by "line division"? Also, what would `display_w` be?

Comment: “line division” wasn’t the best wording, but basically from the linked question you can see the text that has to be displayed is just a long string split by using “\n” which should work. “display_w” is just the display width used to position the text and create space between lines(display_w can be replaced by any value to fit the position of text you need) @undonepotato